# How to print '\1' using es6 String.raw

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

`String.raw` seems to be a right way to write embedded command like

```
const command = String.raw`sed -n 's/${hash} \(.*\)/\1/p'
```

But the it doesn't work because `\1` can't be written in String.raw, the problem shows below:

```
console.log(String.raw`\1`)
=>SyntaxError: Octal literals are not allowed in template strings.

console.log(String.raw`\\1`)
\\1
```

Comment: There's a proposal which would allow this: https://github.com/tc39/proposal-template-literal-revision

Answer (score 1, accepted):

only way I can see doing it is

```
let x = '\\1'
const command = String.raw`sed -n 's/${hash} \(.*\)/${x}/p'`
```

@HBP almost made the right call in the comments

```
const command = String.raw`sed -n 's/${hash} \(.*\)/${'\\1'}/p'`
```

looks to be the ideal

Comment: It appears that you can replace the `x` with `'\1'` obviating the need for a new variable

Comment: what do you mean @HBP? `${'\1'}`? not quite ... however, `${'\\1'}` works